# Is there an easy way to change cell references in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I recently developed a model for work and I am getting requests for adding additional features.

The problem isn't making the additions as most simply involve adding one or two additional columns. However, each time I add a column I must go through my code line by line and change every formula reference e.g. G to H, H to I, I to J etc.

Is there any way for me to automate this process without having to change each formula individually or a best practice that I can keep in mind when building my next model from scratch?

For example, let's say someone asks for an additional calculation that requires I insert a formula into column D.  Currently I am going to each column (H, J, K, and L in the example below), and manually updating them to I, K, L, and M, respectively.

```
'Year 1 ASP formula = (Year 1 Bookings) / (Year 1 Units)
FormulaRange_ASP1 = "H23:H" & NumRows
Range(FormulaRange_ASP1).Value = "=IFERROR(G23/F23,0)"
Range(FormulaRange_ASP1).NumberFormat = "0.00"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Year 2 AR Units formula = (Year 1 Units) * (Vlookup AR Retention Rate for product in column C)
FormulaRange_ARUnits2 = "J23:J" & NumRows
Range(FormulaRange_ARUnits2).Value = "=IF(E23 = 12,VLOOKUP(D23,$B$8:$F$19,4,FALSE),0) * F23 * AR_Opt_In"
Range(FormulaRange_ARUnits2).NumberFormat = "#,##0_)"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Year 2 AR ASP formula = (Vlookup ASP for product in column C)
FormulaRange_AR_ASP2 = "K23:K" & NumRows
Range(FormulaRange_AR_ASP2).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D23,$B$8:$F$19,2,FALSE),0)"
Range(FormulaRange_AR_ASP2).NumberFormat = "0.00"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Year 2 AR Bookings formula = (Year 2 Units) * (Year 2 ASP)
FormulaRange_AR_Bookings2 = "L23:L" & NumRows
Range(FormulaRange_AR_Bookings2).Value = "=J23 * K23"
Range(FormulaRange_AR_Bookings2).NumberFormat = "$#,##0_)"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code please?

Comment: I'm wondering why you need to create all these formulas in code. If you just created them in a worksheet (perhaps a template?) the formulas would adjust automatically when columns are added or deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is add some constants to the beginning of the module (or a separate module, for bigger projects) with column number references.

```
Const c_Column1 As Integer = 1
Const c_Column2 As Integer = 2
```

So, throughout the code, you can do something like:

```
For i = 2 to 10
   ActiveSheet.Cells(i, c_Column1).Value = i
Next i
```

.. and never have to worry about changing your code, only the constants.

Notice the use of `Cells()` instead of `Range()`, because it allows referencing the columns as numbers. To reference a range, you'll have to use the following sintax:

```
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 to 10
        .Range(.Cells(i, c_Column1), .Cells(i, c_Column2)).Value = i
    Next i
End With
```

You can also declare the constants as `String` and assign them column letters instead of numbers. It may be easier to reference ranges, but you'll have to use string concatenation everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use relative R1C1 references.

E.g. instead of specifying a formula in H23 as:

```
Range(FormulaRange_ASP1).Value = "=IFERROR(G23/F23,0)"
```

You can specify it as:

```
Range(FormulaRange_ASP1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(R[0]C[-1]/R[0]C[-2],0)"
```